# Why does blur event never fire if Chrome developer tools debugger is triggered?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Consider this input - we blur on pressing enter.

It normally works. But if you open Devtools, so the debugger line works, then !!blur never fires - even though the element loses focus!

Why, what's going on?

And is there a way to get a reliable blur event?

(It's not just Devtools/debugger - there seem to be other cases where this can happen, such as if the window is out of focus, but I haven't dug deep enough yet to have anything concrete to report here.)

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('blur', () => console.log('!!blur'));

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('focus', () => console.log('!!focus'));

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log("!!enter");
    debugger;
    e.target.blur();
  }
});
```

```html
<input>

<p>Try compare opening / closing devtools and pressing enter - !!blur is missing when open!</p>
```

Comment: When I open DevTools I get `!!blur`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me using your code on the stack overflow input. Maybe you are not really blurring yourself ? I just exit the input and it works, chrome dev tools open or not.

Blur even works, with your code, on focus lost. So I'm confused.

One thing that could capture blur is a chrome extension ? Maybe you have something logging your inputs to capture crypto currency keys, or other such malware ? What happens on incognito with no extension loaded ?